# Laravel | search id table1

Tags: laravel

I need help for this problem.

I need to store data in two tables. But I want them to have the same ID. i.e. I want to write data in table 1 and then in table 2 where I want the ID of table 1 to be equal to that of table 2

```
 $tabela = new funcionario();
 $tabela->nome = $request->nome;
 $tabela->email = $request->email;
 

$tabela2 = new utilizador();
$tabela2->id = ID da tabela
$tabela2->Address = $request->Address ;
```

the result would be:

Table 1
ID - (auto increment) 10
name - Example
Email - Example@test.com

Table 2
ID - same as ID table 1 (10)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good approach, maybe you need the foreign key for your one to one relationship but you can add `id` to your model `fillable` or add it with the active record:

```
 $tabela = new funcionario();
 $tabela->nome = $request->nome;
 $tabela->email = $request->email;
 

$tabela2 = new utilizador();
$tabela2->id = $tablea->id;
$tabela2->Address = $request->Address ;
```

Comment: I think its best to use the relational model and use foreign keys to attach the records.